# Puppeteer - how to iterate through queryObjects to collect the url of a WebSocket object?

Tags: websocket, puppeteer, google-chrome-headless, headless-browser

I am using Puppeteer in a Node.js module. I retrieve a WebSocket object Prototype with queryObjects and I need to extract the url property.

```
    // Get a handle to the websocket object prototype
    
    const prototypeHandle = await page.evaluateHandle(() => WebSocket.prototype);
    
    // Query all websocket instances into a jsHandle object
    
    const jsHandle = await page.queryObjects(prototypeHandle);
    
    // Count amount of map objects in heap
    
    // const count = await page.evaluate(maps => maps.length, jsHandle); // returns the expected amount (x2)

    // How to iterate through jsHandle to collect the url of each websockets

    await jsHandle.dispose();
    await prototypeHandle.dispose();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not get any response because WebSocket is not a simple JSON object which can be stringified and given back to you when you evaluate using page.evaluate.

To get the URL of the connected websocket in the page, you can map through the collected WebSocket instances/objects and extract the url out of them.

```js
const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
const page = (await browser.pages())[0];

// create a dummy websocket connection for testing purpose
await page.evaluate(() => new WebSocket('wss://echo.websocket.org/'));


const wsPrototypeHandle = await page.evaluateHandle(
  () => WebSocket.prototype
);

const wsInstances = await page.queryObjects(wsPrototypeHandle);

const wsUrls = await page.evaluate(
  (e) => e.map((e) => e['url']), // <-- simply access the object here
  wsInstances
);

console.log(wsUrls);
```

Which will result in following,

```
[ 'wss://echo.websocket.org/' ]
```